# Managing Admob publisher ID from a central place with multiple ad placements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, admob, ads

So, with new google-admob SDK for android correct way to place banner ad in the layout is for example like this :

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="some id"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

My problem is that I have multiple banner ads throughout various activities and when I for some reason want to change adUnitId I do not want to chase this snippet of code through all my xml layout files. I want to have one place where I define my adUnitId that all banner ads in the app uses. That was possible in the previous admob-only SDK, by setting meta data in manifest file. And I do not want to layout AdView in Java code, want it to be in xml if possible with the new SDK.
I tried with something like this :

```
ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
```

but it just see it as a string as I can see, not following through to the actual string defined in the strings.xml. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest admob update, I was forced to do most of my AdMob activities in my Java classes.  This is how I made it work (with a centralized ID):

```
ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, UtilClass.AD_PUBLISHER_ID); //Ad is the global AdView
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_admob_layout);
```

Edit:  I keep the `LinearLayout` definition in the xml files so the positioning is all done throughout the xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="bottom" android:weightSum="0"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/main_admob_layout">
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid such solution. I do not want to define AdView layout through Java code and position it in LinearLayout or whatever Layout through code. I like and want to keep all possible UI stuff in the xml files.

Comment: I still have the Ad layout in the xml file.  I updated to show it.

Comment: Thanks, I did not got the idea first because part of the code is missing. Rating as solved. Just an addon question. Do you have problems sometime with ads not showing, using this setup? Because admob could be picky about where and how it can bi placed. I just only this : **android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"** for my LinearLayout in which I add admob baner ad with no LayoutParams set. It works, just asking if there is something to be known.